# How to install Apache Superset in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: bigdata, apache-superset

I am following the steps laid out here:

https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-using-docker-compose

I run running one by one:

> We recommend that you check out and run the code from the last tagged
> release
>
> $ git checkout latest
>
> Then, run the following command:
>
> $ docker-compose up

And I am getting this error:

> WARNING: The CYPRESS_CONFIG variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank
> string.
> ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon - you might need to run `docker-machine start default`.

I am not able to find how to install and start default server with docker-machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this command before `docker-compose up`:

```
export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

It will export DOCKER_HOST to environment variables and help docker client to find a connection to Docker daemon.